# Can I bring nicotine patches for personal use into Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, smoking

I am going to Australia for a holiday. I am using nicotine patches to quit smoking. I can't find any information, whether nicotine patches are allowed by Autralia Customs. On the official website, they only refer to e-cigarettes and fluid.

Comment: Nicotine patches are widely available over-the-counter in Australian supermarkets and pharmacies, so you may not necessarily need to bring them to Australia.

Answer (score 1):

You will be fine to bring them to Australia, keep the packaging incase they're checked, also do not bring more than 3 months worth. You should also declare it on your landing card, as the [Arriving into Australia webpage](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/can-you-bring-it-in) says.

> The traveller's exemption allows people entering Australia to carry their medicines and medical devices with them for their own personal use or the use by an immediate family member who is travelling with them, such as an infant.
>
> 1. Follow these simple rules to make sure you don't get caught up at the
>      border:
> 2. Don't bring medicines or medical devices into Australia for anyone
>      other than yourself or an immediate family member.
> 3. For prescription
>      medicines, bring the prescription with you or have a letter from your
>      doctor that outlines what you are taking and how much you are bringing
>      with you.
> 4. Keep the original packaging for your medicines and medical
>      devices intact so they can be easily identified.
> 5. Do not bring more
>      than a 3 month supply with you.
> 6. Check what medicines need to be
>      declared at the border at the Department of Home Affairs website on
>      the [Arriving into Australia webpage](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/can-you-bring-it-in). You must declare any medicines
>      which may be subject to abuse or misuse. This includes steroids,
>      strong pain medicines, cannabis and other restricted medicines.
> 7. Injections that contain material of human or animal origin, such as
>      growth hormone, require special permission to bring into the country.
>      An Australian doctor must organise access for you through the [Special
>      Access Scheme](https://www.tga.gov.au/form/special-access-scheme). You do not need permission to bring insulin with you
>      for personal use.

https://www.tga.gov.au/entering-australia